# How to sample from a PySpark dataframe where each row has a probability value?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe of 4.000.000 rows, and two columns, `sample_id` and `probability`, where the probability value was computed bu normalizing a weight between 0 and 1.
I have to sample a subset of this dataframe, l rows, based on the `probability` values, so that rows with a larger probability are more likely to be sampled.
I saw some similar questions here on Stack but none of those resolved my issues.

First, I thought I could do it with the cumulative probability, by then generating a random number between 0 and 1 and take the sample for which the cumulative probability was the highest of the values lower than the random value, but I encountered some problems in computing the cumulative probability for each row; I did it like this:

```
window_spec = Window.orderBy('sample_id')

# Calculate cumulative probability using a window function
df = df.withColumn('cumulative_prob', sum('probability').over(window_spec))
```

With this code, however, the maximum cumulative_prob was not 1 and I couldn't resolve the issue.
Is there a way to better compute the cumulative probability or a more efficient way to perform a sampling given my initial dataframe?
Thanks in advance and sorry if it's a trivial question.

Comment: 1) A `Window.orderBy('sample_id')` will simply order your dataframe by sample_id; 2) I am not 100% sure how you're planning to "sample a subset", but perhaps finding a simple average or [`percentile()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile) / `percentile_approx` of `probability` and then `filter()`ing the dataframe based on it would do it?